# Replace strings in PHP files with shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Good morning to everyone here, attempt to replace a series of characters in different PHP files taking into account the following:

The files are lines like this:

```
if($_GET['x']){
```

And so I want to replace:

```
if(isset($_GET['x'])){
```

But we must take into account that there are files in lines like the following, but they do not want to modify the

```
if($_GET["x"] == $_GET["x"]){
```

I try as follows but I can not because I change all lines containing `$ _GET ["x"]`

My example:

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -exec ./code.sh {} \;

sed -i 's/\ if($_GET['x']){/ if(isset($_GET['x'])){/' "$1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g" --
```

The pattern above for `if($_GET['x']){` would never match `if($_GET["x"] == $_GET["x"]){`.

Update:

This would change `if($_GET['x']){` or `if($_GET["x"]){` to `if(isset($_GET['x'])){`:

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e "s|if *(\$_GET\[[\"']x[\"']\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g" --
```

Another update:

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e "s|if *(\$_GET\[[\"']\([^\"']\+\)[\"']\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['\1'])){|g" --
```

Would change anything in the form of `if($_GET['<something>']){` or `if($_GET["<something>"]){`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, but this code still did not make any change :(

Comment: What's the output of `sed --version`? Any other error message you see?

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2, not replace me `$ _GET ['x']` for `isset ($ _GET ['x'])` ignoring lines that are like this `$ _GET ['x'] == $ _GET ['x']`

Comment: Mine is actually just 4.2.1. What do you get if you do `echo "if(\$_GET['x']){" | sed -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g"`?

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['x'])){`
`if(isset($_GET['x'])){`

Comment: Perhaps you haven't add `-i` to `sed` in the main command? I made some edit earlier.

Comment: if I return it on screen, and I have 2 files. php

Comment: would look like?

`find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e echo "if(\$_GET['x']){" | sed -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g"`

Comment: No same command: `find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g" --`

Comment: I suggest trying to debug it first. See if `find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 echo` produces file list. Then see if `sed -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g" somefile.php` changes the intended strings. It should work if both works or otherwise not.

Comment: if you run the following:
`find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 echo`
shows the following:
`./indexback.php ./index.php`

if you ran the following loading freezes
`sed -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g"`

Comment: You're probably referring as well to other instances of `$_GET['x']` where it's not just part of `if($_GET['x'])`?

Comment: You had to add the file to `sed -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g"`: `sed -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g somefile.ph`. Or else it would just read stdin and just freeze.

Comment: Shows the following with: 
`sed -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g"`

indexback.php index.php

`<?php
     if($_GET["x"] == $_GET["x"]){
         echo 'valor 3';
     }else{
      
     }
?>
<?php
     if($_GET["x"]){
         echo 'valor 1';
     }else{
       echo 'valor 2';
     }
?>`

Comment: No understanding, according to me and I'm doing well but does not leave

Comment: Since then thank you very much for your patience, first run the following to run a file called code.sh:

`find . -name "*.php" -type f -exec ./codeh {} \;`

Which contains the following statement:
`sed -e "s|if *(\$_GET\['x'\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g" "$1"`

Comment: And I displayed:
`<?php
     if($_GET["x"] == $_GET["x"]){
         echo 'valor 3';
     }else{
      
     }
?><?php
     if($_GET["x"]){
         echo 'valor 1';
     }else{
       echo 'valor 2';
     }
?>`
What is the content of my 2 files which I am doing tests..

Comment: You're still using the old sed code for that. Please use the second version in my update of this post: `find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e "s|if *(\$_GET\[[\"']x[\"']\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g" --`

Comment: One last question, to find suitable matches could be?
`find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e "s|if *(\$_GET\[[\"']x[\"']\])" --`

Comment: Sorry, do you mean just printing them and not substituting? You can just use grep: `find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -e "if *(\$_GET\[[\"']x[\"']\])"`. Add `-l` as an option (`grep -l -e ...`) if you just want to print the file's name.

Comment: Thanks! And if the value of 'x' will change? sorry but I'm newbie friend, I mean it can be $ _GET ['x'], $ _GET ['y'], $ _GET ['z'] etc ...

Comment: You mean if you try to alter other values than x? Probably it would just be the same: `find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e "s|if *(\$_GET\[[\"']a b c[\"']\]) *{|if(isset(\$_GET['a b c'])){|g"`. Just make sure you also change the value to substitute. We can do a safer variation not needing to change the substitute value but it might just get more confusing now we already have a working code.

Comment: It is only in some cases is no $ _GET ['x'], but also $ _GET ['w'], and here only to replace the 'x' or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes you're correct. Just make sure you don't only replace the first one (`if *(\$_GET\[[\"']x[\"']\]) *{`) but also the second one (`if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g`).

Comment: And as you may also change the $ _GET ['w'], $ _GET ['x'], $ _GET ['o'], meaning that not only 'x' that contains $ _GET [''] .. .

Comment: so? `find . -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e "if *(\$_GET\[[\"']x[\"']\]) *{if(isset(\$_GET['x'])){|g" --`

Comment: No I mean [my answer itself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24167726/445221). Please check it again. The third update is the answer for matching anything similar and changing them.

Comment: Listo muschisimas gracias!